# Can I run a water line from my well pump to a remote spigot?

Tags: water, water-pressure, well, well-pump, water-filtration

We just moved into our house and it has a well system with a pump; everything works fine. On top of the pump, there is a water spigot to bypass the filtration system. On the outside of the house on all sides, we have spigots where you can attach a garden hose to. We also have 4 horses that live on our property.

Initially, my plan was to run a Pex line from one of the outside spigots to where the barn is using a Waterworks Hidden Hydrant for convenience and not having hoses laying all over the yard that I have to move when I mow.

Then we were told by our local water company that the outside house spigots are tied into our water filtration system and if we used it for sprinklers or feeding the horses (we live in Florida and they drink A LOT), that it would deplete our home's clean water. We could upgrade the system for a charge of course, or they suggested that we use the spigot that's attached to the top of our pump which bypasses the filtration system.

So what I did now was run the Pex line from the pump spigot to the fence line by the barn and that's where I have the Waterworks Hidden Hydrant.

The problem I am encountering is that when I turn the pump spigot on, but the Waterworks Hidden Hydrant is off, there seems to be a back pressure attachment on the pump, which spews out water off the pump spigot! When the Waterworks Hidden Hydrant is turned on, it works fine.

My question - and bear in mind, this is new to me - is, what do I need to do to make this work? Am I safe to remove the back pressure attachment on the pump spigot OR do I need to add something so that I don't cause any damage to the pump/system?

Pump and Spigot:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hydrant:

[image]

Water flow:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: lots of words trying to describe, a picture would help

Comment: Install a T junction before the back pressure valve

Comment: @Ruskes, I added pics - I just hadn't gone outside yet to get them. So a T junction would be before the Pex line?

Comment: Thank you, now we can see what you see. The back-pressure valve still has to fulfill its function, so it has to be inline

Comment: @Ruskes, thank you and apologies, I am not 100% clear on what you mean? The back-pressure valve is attached to the spigot on the pump and your recommendation is to install a t-junction before the back pressure valve - do you mean to install the T in between the Pex line and the spigot with the back-pressure valve? So it would be pump/spigot/back-pressure -> line -> t-junction -> line to hydrant?

Comment: Question Zero - what is in your water that needs filtering out? Is it bad for horses? Does that affect your choice of water source for horses...?

Comment: @Ecnerwal, thank you - from the well nothing needs to be filtered for the horses. The only filtering needed is for the house. For drinking, we have reverse osmosis.

Comment: Where is the "back pressure attachment" on the pump and where does water spew out? Adding some arrows or circles to your existing pics would be helpful. Also, are you sure it's not a "back flow preventer" or vacuum break? That would make sense to ensure that the diverted water isn't going back into the (human) drinking water system.

Comment: @FreeMan, thank you - added water flow picture for you, but it flows out the back if the hydrant is turned off and water pressure builds up. I believe it's a vacuum breaker that's attached to the spigot.

Comment: The short-term solution is to close the valve at the pump with the black handle. That will stop pressure in the line leading to the hydrant. Of course, you'll still get some spray while you're on your way between the two locations, and when you need to (briefly) turn the water off at the hydrant. I'm sure someone else will be along with a better, long-term solution.

Comment: @FreeMan, that's what we're doing today and kiiiiinda defeats the purpose of running the line for the hydrant - I was hoping I would be able to turn on/off the water at the hydrant as the pump is on the opposite side of the property/house. Its more about convenience - I already have a (green) hose running from the pump to the area I need the water, but this involves walking all the way back and forth. The idea of running a line to the hydrant was so that we can control the water closer to the barn area and not have to walk over to the pump every time. Thanks!

Comment: As noted, a short-term solution.

Comment: @FreeMan, understood - but this is why I posted on here, to avoid having to continue the short-term solution we're currently using. Its not a huge deal to walk back and forth, but like I said, more about convenience. I am hoping to avoid having to tap another line which I don't think we don't need. At our barn prior, which is in the same neighborhood, they have one well and have additional lines running to the horse area. Unfortunately, it was done 20 years ago. If I have to call a company, I will - but again, kinda why I posted here for help. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an unfiltered spigot? We just had a house built and the plumber left one spigot unfiltered so we could wash our filter housing when changing well filters.

Comment: @RetiredATC, the spigot coming off the pump is unfiltered. That’s where I’ve tapped this line from so it gets water before it gets into the filtered system.

Comment: I'm sorry, my comment wasn't clear. Are you sure you don't have an unfiltered spigot on your house?

Comment: @RetiredATC, yes we confirmed w the builder that the spigots on the outside of the house all feed off the w filtered system. No idea why they did that, but they did. Our house is leas than 3 months old, we just moved in.